# Maven overlays and jetty plugin

Tags: java, maven, jetty, overlays

I am using Maven overlays and include a dependent war in pom as follows

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.test.dependent</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>war</type>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The generated war files looks fine, it contains the resources out of both projects and if I deploy it to my tomcat server everything works as expected.

However I am used to use to jetty plugin in maven and run my builds with goal jetty:run

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  <finalName>myproject</finalName>
</build>
```

Unfortunately it looks like jetty would not include the files from the dependent project. How can I configure the plugin to take the dependent projects into account?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that the `maven-war-plugin` packages overlays automatically (I always add an explicit `<overlays>` section to the config), but if that's true, simply running `mvn package jetty:run` should work, since `jetty:run` also checks the target directory.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, although in my target folder it looks like all files would be there and so they are in the war file, the files from the dependent project are not accessible via browser

Comment: Just noticed: When starting jetty I get the log message

[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\paul\develop\myproject\src\main\webapp

In this file I of course don't have the files from the dependent project. Any idea how to configure jetty in order to take the files from target?

Comment: @Paul : other than the aforementioned explicit definition of overlays in the `war-plugin` config, I have no idea - it works out of the box for me otherwise. I do use a much more recent version of `maven-jetty-plugin`, though (`6.1.25`).

Comment: The current `jetty-maven-plugin` version is `9.1.0.v20131115` - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html.   Jetty 6 was EOL in 2010.  As of today, there have been 151 releases of Jetty since Jetty 6.1.10.

Comment: And the more recent jetty-9 maven plugins certainly support the maven-war-plugin overlays. See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#using-overlaid-wars

Answer (score 0):

On [Jetty 7.0.2 and higher](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1027) you can use `jetty:run` with `unpackOverlays` configuration:

```
<webAppConfig>
    ...
    <unpackOverlays>true</unpackOverlays>
    ...        
</webAppConfig>
```

On Jetty 6, your only option is to use `jetty:run-war` for that.